# ASP.NET MVC: How do I send "text/xml" to all browsers but IE?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, xhtml, svg, content-type

I need to be able to send the content type "text/xml" to Firefox and Safari, to allow them to render inline SVG in one of my pages.

This works, as long as the content type is "text/xml".

However, when IE hits the page, if the content type is not "text/html" it tries to render the XML document tree, rather than the XHTML content of the page.

**What is the "right way" in ASP.NET MVC to set the HTTP Content-Type of ALL of my views?**

Keep in mind that I am going to be rendering the views as ViewResults.

Ok, to clear any confusion up:

```
User Agent    Content-Type Desired
-----------------------------------
IE 5.5        text/html
IE 6          text/html
IE 7          text/html
IE 8          text/html
Firefox       text/xml
Safari        text/xml
Chrome        text/xml
```

And so on.

All of the browsers listed support SVG inline in some way or another.  I have a consistent delivery format, save the content type.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Your subject suggests that you want to have text / xml as document type for all browsers except IE. The question itself seems as if you want text / html for all views.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use application/xhtml+xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to W3, you should be using `application/xhtml+xml` rather than `text/xml` to signify XHTML:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/NOTE-xhtml-media-types-20020801/#text-xml

The above article also notes that `text/html` should *not* be used for XHTML content.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I realize all of this.  However, if I use a content type OTHER THAN text/html, IE WILL NOT RENDER IT.

Comment: No need to get snippy. As far as I can tell, IE does in fact render XHTML correctly when using the application/xhtml+xml content type. Can you post an example in your question of the content that is not rendering correctly?

Comment: The problem I run into is when I try to use a XHTML doctype, the MSXML parser ends up throwing an error reading the document, citing an issue with the order that entities are declared in the doctype.

Answer (score 5):

You *could* look at the properties in `Request.Browser` and sniff out IE that way, and return the proper view that way, though that is prone to issues. This isn't optimal because IE *might* support it in the future.

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
  if (this.Request.Browser.Browser == "IE") {
    return View("NonSVG");
  } else {
    return View("SVG");
  }
}
```

Something worth looking into a little more might be this [page on Codeplex](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Capabilities). They define a property on `Browser` called `AcceptsImageSVG`, but it looks like it's geared towards mobile browsers, don't know if it could be used in your situation.

Comment: Another issue is that some people spoof user agents.

Comment: The thing is, IE supports inline SVG.  I have that working using the AdobeSVG.  The only thing I need is for the save view to have two different content-types.

Answer (score 2):

You can determine the browser type by using the Request.Browser object

See this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.type%28VS.80%29.aspx

So you could do something like:

```
if( Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("IE") )
{
  // Return IE View
}
else
{
  // Return the other view
}
```

Or, if you use this in lots of places you could create a ViewResult factory that returns the proper view result based on the browser type.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hacky, but... What if the SVG was in a frame, the frame advertised content-type=text/xml, while the containing page advertsized the more proper application/xhtml+xml. This divides the problem into two (possibly) more tractable ones.

Comment: That is actually pretty close to what I actually did.  However, I used an `object` instead of an `iframe`.  Check it out: http://lanlordz.net/Events/ViewTournament/2

Comment: Actually, that tournament never had a bracket.  Try this one instead: http://lanlordz.net/Events/ViewTournament/4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will work, but you *could* try using [conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if gt IE 8]>-->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" />
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <title>Test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Test page</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or, better yet, use HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Test page</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

You don't even need to specify the content type.